# Why does v4l2src error message not propragate through pipeline that contains queue element?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, usb-camera

I am trying to build a gstreamer pipeline that takes a video stream from h264 USB camera and does something with it (display it on screen, record it to a file, ect.). If an error occures in pipeline, I would like to print it out and terminate the pipeline. For example:
If USB camera gets unplugged, the pipeline should terminate and there should be an error message printed out.

Using the following simple pipeline works as desired:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! decodebin !  autovideosink
```

The pipeline displays the video and when I unplug the camera, the pipeline terminates and prints the following output:

```
v4l2src0: 
Error: gst-resource-error-quark: Could not read from resource. (9)
Debug: gstv4l2bufferpool.c(1040): gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_poll (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
poll error 1: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
```

When I was building a more complex pipeline (that fits my needs), I found out that the error message was not propagated through the pipeline and thus it did not terminate the pipeline. I narrow it down to the "trouble maker" element and it turns out to be the **queue** element.

The following pipeline does not work as desired anymore:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! queue ! decodebin !  autovideosink
```

When camera is unplugged the video display freezes indefinitely without terminating the pipeline.

Is this a normal behavior? What am I missing? Is there a workaround?

PS.: I tried to simulate an error message with **identity** element and its **error-after** property.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! identity error-after=60 ! queue ! decodebin !  autovideosink
```

This pipeline also works as desired, meaning it gets terminated with a relevant error message.

Comment: Did you learn any more about this problem since posting? I've also noticed that when using "udpsrc async=false" it would also hide any errors on USB unplug as well.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not find an answer for my question.